# Get SMS sent using Azure Communication Services

Tags: node.js, azure-communication-services

We were using Twilio to manage sending SMS from our product. Twilio has an API that allows us to fetch messages sent from a given account, to a given phone number. We are using this in our end-to-end testing scenarios to get a SMS message sent from our platform and validate its contents.

We had to change from Twilio to Azure Communication Services for business-related reasons. I've looked through the ACS docs, yet could not find a way to get messages sent from us to a given number. Is there a way to do it that i'm missing?

For example, here is what it looks like using the Twilio node library:

```
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
module.exports = async (phoneNumber) => {
  const today = DateTime.now();
  const sentDate = new Date(today.year, today.month - 1, today.day, today.hour, today.minute - 1);
  try {
    const messages = await client.messages.list({
      limit: 10,
      to: phoneNumber,
      dateSentAfter: sentDate,
    });
    return messages;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return null;
  }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

I looked into the documentation for Azure Communication Services but I am unable to find any information regarding fetching SMS sent from your account.